# Audio not working in YouTube player helper app

Tags: xcode, audio, video, youtube, plist

I'm writing an app that plays videos from YouTube using the YouTube helper library ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#controlling_playback ).

The video works well, but when it plays there is no audio. I am new to using audio in apps, so it is quite possible that there is a very simple setting that I need to change in my xcode project, but I don't know what it is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that my phone was simply on silent. YTPlayerView cannot produce any sound when the ring/silent switch is in the silent position

Comment: Does this problem still persist with the YTPlayer-Helper ? or you have find some way to work this out

Comment: I am also facing the same issue & trying to get this fixed, "requirement": need to play the sound even if the iPhone is in ringer silent mode.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can make the YTPlayerView reproduce sound even with the switch in the silent position: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23288908/1681789)

Answer (score 0):

To play Youtube even when in silent mode, add the following to your code. Can be anywhere, like in AppDelegate:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
}
catch {
    // report for an error
}
```

Original code copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35290370/956620)

Answer (score 0):

YoutubePlayer cannot produce any sound when the ring/silent switch is in the silent position and sound will be active