# Play Audio when device in silent mode - ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I am creating an application using xcode 7.1, swift. I want to play an audio. Everything is fine. Now my problem I want to hear sound when the device in silent mode or muted. How can I do it?

I am using the following code to play audio

```
currentAudio!.stop()
currentAudio = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample_audio", ofType: "mp3")!));
            
currentAudio!.currentTime = 0
currentAudio!.play();
```

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Put this line before calling **play()** method of AVPlayer.

**In Objective C**

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
            setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                  error: nil];
```

**In Swift**

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
} catch {
    // report for an error
}
```

**Swift 5**

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
} catch(let error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: The import is: `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Comment: Small nitpick: for the "catch" you don't need to specify (let error) since swift will do this for you.

Comment: Note that this also works to get audio from an AVPlayer to play while in silent mode too!

Answer (score 26):

You can use `AppDelegate` class.

**For enable sound (for audio or video) when device is in silent mode use [AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryplayback):**

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {  
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    } catch {
        print("AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback not work")
    }
}
```

**For disable sound when device is in silent mode (for example when we answer the phone call) use [AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategorysoloambient):**

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient)
    } catch {
        print("AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient not work")
    }
}
```

Comment: Enabling "AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient",  Picture in Picture in the player controls is gone!

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4**

use this line before play video

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])
```

Comment: it's for iOS10+ only

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3.0 and Xcode > 8

Play sound in Video when device is on RINGER mode and SLIENT mode

```
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        //print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            //print("AVAudioSession is Active")
        } catch _ as NSError {
            //print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch _ as NSError {
        //print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: Hello. This is wrong: `catch _ as NSError`. Just use `catch` in this case. Do not downcast to a discarded value, this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6):

> Swift 4.2

```
   do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])
    } catch let error {
        print("Error in AVAudio Session\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5.0.1**

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can go through this,  it will help you out

When you use following audio session categories, sounds will not be muted on iOS: `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback,AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord,AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`

**Example**

```
    func playSound (Sound: String, Type: String) {

        //Prepare the sound file name & extension
        var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(Sound, ofType: Type)!)

        //Preparation to play
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

        //Play audio

        var error: NSError?
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share some example

Comment: OP is using Swift 2 (they mention Xcode 7.1 in the question). Your example is for Swift 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
import AVKit
```

And add this to your AppDelegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive` section

```
   func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
            print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                print("AVAudioSession is Active")
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```