# Is there any relationship between an AVAudioEngine and an AVAudioSession?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I understand that this question might get a bad rating, but I've been looking at questions which ask how to reroute audio output to the loud speaker on iOS devices.

Every question I looked at the user talked about using your `AVAudioSession` to reroute it.. However, I'm not using `AVAudioSession`, I'm using an `AVAudioEngine`.

So basically my question is, even though I'm using an `AVAudioEngine`, should I still have an `AVAudioSession`?

If so, what is the relationship between these two objects? Or is there a way to connect an `AVAudioEngine` to an `AVAudioSession`?

---

If this is not the case, and there is no relation between an `AVAudioEngine` and an `AVAudioSession`, than how do you reroute audio so that it plays out of the main speakers on an iOS device rather than the earpiece.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation? o_O

Comment: Sound is sound. The AVAudioSession always matters

Comment: @l'L'l yes, I've tried looking at the documentation, but I honestly haven't found it to be very informative.

Comment: @matt So even though I haven't explicitly setup an AVAudioSession it is still being used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**AVAudioSession** is specific to iOS and coordinates audio playback between apps, so that, for example, audio is stopped when a call comes in, or music playback stops when the user starts a movie. This API is needed to make sure an app behaves correctly in response to such events

**AVAudioEngine** is a modern Objective-C API for playback and recording. It provides a level of control for which you previously had to drop down to the C APIs of the Audio Toolbox framework (for example, with real-time audio tasks). The audio engine APIs are built to interface well with lower-level APIs, so you can still drop down to Audio Toolbox if you have to.

The basic concept of this API is to build up a graph of audio nodes, ranging from source nodes (players and microphones) and overprocessing nodes (mixers and effects) to destination nodes (hardware outputs). Each node has a certain number of input and output busses with well-defined data formats. This architecture makes it very flexible and powerful. And it even integrates with audio units.

so there is no inclusive relation between this .

Source Link : https://www.objc.io/issues/24-audio/audio-api-overview/

Comment: So if I were to edit the AVAudioSession, would this affect the way that AVAudioEngine is used? For example if I set my AVAudioSession to use PlayAndRecord type, would this affect my AVAudioEngine in anyway?

Comment: Then how to play sound even when device in silent mode? Every answer says use session. But I don't think oscillators use session. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289918/play-audio-when-device-in-silent-mode-ios-swift

edit: actually, I just started a totally new/unrelated AVAudioSession, edited it, it works!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is not clearly commented , however, I found this comment from ios developer documentation.

> AVFoundation playback and recording classes automatically activate your audio session.

Document Link : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringanAudioSession/ConfiguringanAudioSession.html

I hope this may help you.