# Audio is not playing in uiwebview in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i want to play live streaming video in uiwebview it is playing by believe code

```
UIWebView *web=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[web loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
web.scalesPageToFit=YES;
web.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=NO;
[self.view addSubview: web];
```

but the problem is that audio is not playing in simulator or not in any device with that live video what i am doing wrong or what i have missed here

Comment: Try adding `web.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;` and load the html after setting all properties.

Comment: And you should probably use `WKWebView` instead, as recommended by Apple for iOS 8 and higher.

Comment: web.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES; this is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with not getting sound in device when play youtube video in UIWebView in IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288765/issue-with-not-getting-sound-in-device-when-play-youtube-video-in-uiwebview-in-i)

Comment: no its not duplicate because in that case, in simulator sounds play but in my case also in simulator sound do not play

Comment: And your volume is on?

Answer (score 0):

go to Info.plist property list - add a new row - select required background modes, there should be a subrow called Item 0, select app plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay.  Also check Audio air play in background modes in compatibility.